# A close vote option about "lack of attention" should definitely not be used

Tags: feature-request

I saw this custom reason for close voting:

[image]

Any question that falls under this category should simply be closed as "unclear what you're asking". It needs more detail, so, [as Eliah Kagan says](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7227/38094), why not vote to close it immediately?! It is not going to help the site by staying there.

Besides, how long should we wait before VTCing? A day? two days? a week? a year?

Also, it assumes all users of the site who don't watch their questions are male.

This has some issues that need to be dealt with.

I would have suggested:

> Other: This question is off-topic because it is unanswered, and the
> original asker has abandoned it for at least {amount of time} despite requests
> for additional detail.

Comment: What question is that?

Comment: Oh dear, something tells me I am making a fool of myself...

Comment: Still, where did you saw that?

Comment: @Braiam It was http://askubuntu.com/review/close/249809

Comment: I really don't know why that close reason was used. It's essentially a non-valid close reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't a new close reason, but a custom close reason.

If you find that a custom close reason does not fit with what is listed in the help center, then you can flag the question saying "custom close reason in not vald" or something like that, I once found a new user that voted to close because "because of getting downvotes"

Comment: I jumped to conclusions. But it still should have been closed as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed.

A "lack of attention" question might affect real users. In my mind, this is the same as a "won't fix" bug. "Won't fix" is okay when you have business deadlines, but is useless to an open source community. People affected by such issues should be able to seek the support of the community is dealing with the issues, and should be free to constantly ask "But why?"

The move from XFree86 to Xorg was partially due to this, and constantly asking a question about the status quo should not be discouraged.